# Python 2.7 Issues running functions with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 My code for function `pop(y,p)` works perfectly but the function `aveChange(p,y)` returns multiple printed lines and I need it to only print 1 line that says the average of the yearly changes in population.

And the function `change(p,y,b)` just says:

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
def biggerThan():
    l=raw_input('Enter a list of numbers, separate each number with a    comma:').split(',')
    a=map(int,l)
    n=int(raw_input('Enter another number:'))
    a2=[i for i in a if i>n]
    print a2

    p = [151868, 153982, 156393, 158956, 161884, 165069, 168088, 
    171187, 174149, 177135, 179979, 182992, 185771, 188483, 
    191141, 193526, 195576, 197457, 199399, 201385, 203984, 
    206827, 209284, 211357, 213342, 215465, 217563, 219760, 
    222095, 224567, 227225, 229466, 231664, 233792, 235825, 
    237924, 240133, 242289, 244499, 246819, 249623]
    y1=1950
    y2=1991
    y=range(y1,y2)
def pop(y,p):
    fmt='{:<8}{:<20}{}'
    print(fmt.format('', 'Year', 'Population'))
    for i, (year, pop) in enumerate(zip(y, p)):
        print(fmt.format(i, year, pop))

def aveChange(p,y):
    p = [151868, 153982, 156393, 158956, 161884, 165069, 168088, 
    171187, 174149, 177135, 179979, 182992, 185771, 188483, 
    191141, 193526, 195576, 197457, 199399, 201385, 203984, 
    206827, 209284, 211357, 213342, 215465, 217563, 219760, 
    222095, 224567, 227225, 229466, 231664, 233792, 235825, 
    237924, 240133, 242289, 244499, 246819, 249623]
    y1=1950
    y2=1991
    y=range(y1,y2)
    yearly_change = []
    change=0.0
    total_change=0
    average_change=0
    for i in range(len(p)):
        p[i] = float(p[i])
        #calculate the change in population size for each two years
    for i in xrange(1,len(p)):
        change = p[i] - p[i-1]
        yearly_change.append(change) 
        total_change = float(sum(yearly_change))
        average_change = total_change/40
        print "The average annual change in population during the time period is",average_change

def change(p,y,b):
    p = [151868, 153982, 156393, 158956, 161884, 165069, 168088, 
    171187, 174149, 177135, 179979, 182992, 185771, 188483, 
    191141, 193526, 195576, 197457, 199399, 201385, 203984, 
    206827, 209284, 211357, 213342, 215465, 217563, 219760, 
    222095, 224567, 227225, 229466, 231664, 233792, 235825, 
    237924, 240133, 242289, 244499, 246819, 249623]
    y1=1950
    y2=1991
    y=range(y1,y2)
    yearly_change = []
    newchange=0.0
    greatest_increase=0
    smallest_increase=0
    greatest_year=0
    smallest_year=0
    BASE_YEAR=1950
    for i in range(1,len(p)):
        newchange = p[b] - p[b-1]
        yearly_change.append(newchange)

        if b==1:
            greatest_increase = newchange
            smallest_increase = newchange
            greatest_year = 1
            smallest_year = 1
        else:
            if newchange>greatest_increase:
                greatest_increase = newchange
                greatest_year = b
            elif newchange<smallest_increase:
                smallest_increase = newchange
                smallest_year = b
            print("The year with the greatest increase in population was",
                BASE_YEAR+greatest_year)
            print("The year with the smallest increase in population was",
                BASE_YEAR+smallest_year)
```

Comment: Are the line breaks in your post also in your code?

Comment: Executing this really doesn't raise any `NameError` for me.

Comment: maybe you need only smaller indention in line with `print`

Comment: I just tried reducing the indent on print but still got the error: NameError: name 'b' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `print` statement outside of the `for` loop for `aveChange(p,y)` :

```
for i in xrange(1,len(p)):
    change = p[i] - p[i-1]
    yearly_change.append(change) 
    total_change = float(sum(yearly_change))
    average_change = total_change/40
print "The average annual change in population during the time period is ",average_change
```

For the `change(p, y, b)` function, make sure you are calling it with 3 arguments, and that all of your arguments are defined! You are getting an error because you are calling the function with `b`, but `b` is not defined outside the function before the call!  Try calling it like:

```
change(p, y, 5)
```

Comment: This did fix the aveChange() function. Thank you so much it was making me crazy. I did make sure I was calling the change() function correctly but it still gives me the same error. I am assuming I need to define b better but I am just missing it it think.

Comment: It would help to show how you are calling change().  Several of us can run the code fine when we just copy and paste it and make the call ourselves, it seems.  Is it possible you are not using 2.7 when building?

Comment: I am calling as change(p,y,b)

Comment: I believe I am in 2.7. I am using canopy to edit but I'm not sure how to check to see if it is using 2.7 or 3

Comment: @Mike I have updated my answer and it should fully address your problems, now using the info. from your above comment.

Comment: Thank you soo much. That was such a remedial mistake but I just couldn't grasp it. Thanks.